# ReactJS / NextJS state array not rendering after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, next.js

I am having trouble rendering my objects using ***.map()*** within React / NextJS.

I have a function where I get images from Firebase Cloud Storage, code below:

```
    getImages = () => {
        let firebase = loadFirebase()
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('chest')

        let { state } = this

        storageRef.listAll().then((result) => {
            let data = []

            result.items.forEach((imageRef) => {
                imageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                    data.push(url)
                }).catch((error) => {
                    // Handle any errors
                })
            })

            state.images = data
            this.setState({ images: data })
        }).catch((error) => {
            // Handle any errors
        })
    }
```

This part seems to work as I do get data back and the state is updated, results as in screenshot:
[Results after setState](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTLMc.png)

I then map through images with the code below:

```
{ this.state.images.map((image, index) => {
 return (
    <img
      key={ index }
      src={ image }
      alt=""
    />
  )
})}
```

On the same page as this, I have other places where I get data from Firebase, set my states accordingly and render the objects using ***.map()***. In those cases it works perfectly fine. Difference is that in those cases I use ***getInitialProps()*** to get my data from Firebase, whereas with the data from Cloud Storage I have a function, the ***getImages()*** function above, that is called on ***componentDidMount()***

But in both cases the state is set in ***componentDidMount()*** and the final result returned of ***this.state*** looks like the screenshot attached.

Any help and / or improvements on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never set the state values manually. You should just remove the line that sets the images in the state before calling `setState`. That line prevents the rendering since after that react can not detect any changes when you set the state using `setState`:

```
getImages = () => {
    let firebase = loadFirebase()
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('chest')

    storageRef.listAll().then((result) => {
        let data = []

        result.items.forEach((imageRef) => {
            imageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                data.push(url);
                this.setState({ images: data });
            }).catch((error) => {
                // Handle any errors
            })
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        // Handle any errors
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the only other thing that had to change was moving the `this.setState({ images: data })` below the `data.push(url)` and then it worked.

Comment: If the answer provided worked for you, go ahead and accept it. This lets other people know it was useful to you.